# getting the text from a textview by ContentDescription

Tags: java, android

I have many views(`textview`) generated from while loop and all the same ids for that I try to get content to the textview by `tag`but `tag` gives the first view only  for that I used setContentDescription  ... But I do not know how to get content `textview`by `ContentDescription` in another method

my generate view:

```
    ...............
while (condition) {
    final TextView dec1= (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.dec1);
    final   TextView dec2= (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.dec2);
    final TextView dec3= (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.dec3);
   dec_v1.setContentDescription("a"+dbid);
  dec_v2.setContentDescription("b"+dbid);
  dec_v3.setContentDescription("c"+dbid);
 }
 .................
  public void getD(){
    //here need to get textview content 

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Local cache of added items. 
 * Key - Description Text (ID of item), Value - Text
 */
private final Map<String, TextView> mActiveViews = new HashMap<>();

private method1() {
...............
while (condition) {
    final TextView dec1= (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.dec1);
    final   TextView dec2= (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.dec2);
    final TextView dec3= (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.dec3);

     dec_v1.setContentDescription("a"+dbid);
     mActiveViews.put("a"+dbid, dec1)
     dec_v2.setContentDescription("b"+dbid);
     mActiveViews.put("b"+dbid, dec2)
     dec_v3.setContentDescription("c"+dbid);
     mActiveViews.put("c"+dbid, dec3)
   }
 .................
}


 public void getD() {
    /* Access to all Active TextViews
     */
    for (Map.Entry<String, TextView> entry : mActiveViews.entrySet()) {
          System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }
    /* Another sample with getting specific TextView
     * by your Content Description (Key) 
     */
    System.out.println(mActiveViews.get("a" + dbid));
 }
```

Comment: in getD() how can i get text insiad textview ??

Comment: @mhd See you question above. You wrote `here need to get textview content`. I have added sample, to get textview content.

Comment: i want that by setContentDescription  because i wil using in other method ex: copy content view or delete view so i cant using HashMap

Comment: @mhd I think english isn't your native language. Could you please think, and update your question.

Comment: sorry for my bad english ... Do you have access the textview by ContentDescription ??

Comment: @mhd You can access to the `TextView` by ContentDescription. In my example above, we can just change value to by `TextView`. Is it your question?

Comment: I want to access the textview by ContentDescription because I will use it in other processes such as copying content by ContentDescription  edit content by ContentDescription and more

Comment: Omg, hope I understand, you task. Check answer. @mhd

Comment: Your answer is not what I want .. But you were made in another way .. Anyway thank you so much pls vote my q :D